# How do I install LXDE and the X Window System on Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, xorg, lxde

I recently did a netinstall of Debian Squeeze and during the install I unticked Desktop Environment because I didn't want to install Gnome as the default DE. So I end up with a command line during boot. Now I want to install LXDE and I was wondering which to install: xorg or xserver-xorg (or both) before installing LXDE?

And yes, I realized later that I could have chosen LXDE as an alternative DE during install but I don't want to reinstall again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

```
aptitude install lxde xorg
```

will do.

Longer answer:

The `aptitude show` command will show you a description of a
package and its dependencies from the command line, so you can use
that to decide  whether to install the package or not.  Keep in mind
that `aptitude` and `apt-get` have automated dependency resolution, so
package `lxde` will install the parts of the X Window System that it
needs. (And it's a bug to report if it does not.)

So, on to checking `xorg`:

```
$ aptitude show xorg
[...]
Provides: x-window-system, x-window-system-core
Description: X.Org X Window System
 This metapackage provides the components for a standalone workstation running the X Window System.  It provides the X libraries, an X server, a set of fonts,
 and a group of basic X clients and utilities. 
 [...]
```

So you definitely want `xorg` installed, whatever desktop system you
are going to use.

Comment: Or search the category "Tasks" in aptitude and select the group with your favorite desktop.